# Inequality - Complex Valued Polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

[image]

Note $a_0$ is not equal to $0$ and $\eta$ is positive and sufficiently small.

**Q.** I can't seem to grasp how the inequalities were deduced, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $$|P(\eta\exp i\theta )|\le |a_0|-|b_m|\eta^m+|a_0|\eta^{m+1}\sum_{j=m}^n|b_j|$$
should be 
$$|P(\eta\exp i\theta )|\le |a_0|-|a_m|\eta^m+|a_0|\eta^{m+1}\sum_{j=m}^n|b_j|.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Triangle Inequality, bound using $\eta$ is very small.